# What happens if html5 elements are included in browsers that do not support HTML5?

Tags: html

If the audio tag is included in html page of version lower than html5 then what happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google should be your **first** point of research before asking a question here.  There are plenty of resources that give you the answer.  Including this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens, and the audio isn't displayed. Try it out in the developer tools in internet explorer, using the IE7 emulator, for example.

Comment: ok thanks.Actually when I was testing in my browser of latest version it works. Thanks.